# Use a Graphics2D extended class to draw on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, extends

My question is if there is a way to use my own class that is extended from `Graphics2D` to draw on a `JPanel`?

I tried that out but because the paint method of the panel gives me a `Graphics2D` object. I cannot cast this to my `Graphics` class. I want to write my own graphic methods in that extended class to draw different things and have all the methods at one ordered place to use it. For example, the `Graphics2D.fillRect()` method.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but why can't you use the `drawPolygon` method instead?

Comment: ok soory its not only a shape its like a rectangle with a frame for example and i want to have that all at one place

Comment: Ok, you can still do it with `drawPolygon`. You'll just have to draw multiple polygons to achieve the result.

Comment: @BackSlash yes of cause i can but thats not what i want :D i want to have all my draw mwthods stored in a Graphics2DX, a calss that extends Graphics2D to use it like the drawRect methode or drawPolygon methode. Just with the Graphic instance from the Jpanels paint methode.

Comment: You can't. Swing works with `Graphics` and `Graphics2D` objects, so you'll have to stick with them. You won't be able to cast the `Graphics` which comes inside the `paintComponent` to `Graphics2DX`.

Comment: @BackSlash This is nothing for a commant its more like an answer to my question dont u think ? ;)

Comment: If there is a need to encapsulate the drawing logic, encapsulate it in something like a `MultiPolygon` that has a `draw(Graphics)` method. Call that method from the standard paint method and the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend extending Graphics2D in a class.
What I recommend you do is make `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and then call Graphics2D inside:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

You can rename the g's to whatever you want.
Here is an example of using my 'g' variable:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Looking at all of the comments, I couldn't find one that actually answers the question.